# How to run a applescript (.scpt) programmatically in my OS X app?

Tags: objective-c, applescript

I have a small applescript and I want to run it as soon as a button is pressed in my application, how do I get this done? I've made this OS X app in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NSAppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/index.html) can compile and run AppleScripts.
For example if your script is in the folder `Scripts` in the `Resources` folder

```
NSString *compiledScriptPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myScript" ofType:@"scpt" inDirectory:@"Scripts"];
NSDictionary *error = nil;
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:compiledScriptPath] error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"compile error: %@", error);
} else {
   [script executeAndReturnError:&error];
   if (error) {
     NSLog(@"run error: %@", error);
   }
}
```

Comment: NSAppleScript can take complied scripts (`initWithContentsOfURL`) as well as just literal source text (`initWithSource`)